# Webshere to tomcat migration :HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat8

I am getting a error `could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]` while migrating existing webshere specific project to tomcat. I have changed WebSphereUowTransactionManager to `org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager` becase it supports tomcat. but still facing another issue of region factory

I am migrating my application from webshpere to tomcat and I am getting below error while running tomcat server with web WAR file. Please help me to solve this. I am not sure which hibernate property I have to use while migrating from webshere to tomcat.
I am currently using below property in my persistence xml file

```
    <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>
```

I am using below hibernate jar files

```
        ehcache-core-2.6.6
        hibernate-core-3.6.10.Final
        hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
```

Error:

```
            org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'XXXX' defined in class path resource [config/framework/applicationContext-XX.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
                at .......
            Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: could not instantiate RegionFactory [org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory]
                at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:423)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.determineCacheConcurrencyStrategy(AnnotationBinder.java:1073)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.buildCacheMock(AnnotationBinder.java:1043)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.determineCacheSettings(AnnotationBinder.java:997)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:579)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:4035)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3989)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1398)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1375)
                at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1519)
                at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
                at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1100)
                at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:689)
                at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
                at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
                ... 25 more
            Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
                at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
                at org.hibernate.util.ReflectHelper.classForName(ReflectHelper.java:192)
                at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.createRegionFactory(SettingsFactory.java:409)
                ... 42 more`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory`.

so it looks like you miss the `hibernate-ehcache.jar` in your classpath.

If you use maven as dependency management tool, add the following dependency to your Project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi Jens,Thanks for your reply, I have injected dependency hibernate-ehcache but started getting the new error.

Comment: Hi Jen, Sorry.. I am trying to update the post with full detail but its not allowing me to add complete log.. anyways.. I am getting below error.. Looking at the error it seems like I am missing persistance jar.. but I have not kept such jars when I was using the same project with Webshere....**java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence cannot be found**

Comment: @Java so you miss some other jar's.. The actual is the javax-persistence.jar